# outlook mail-addresses cache

Tags: outlook

in company 2 sites, 2 exchange server 2003.
at site 1 admin remove mailbox for user1 and create new at site 2.
same email address. with external mail no problem,
but local users at site 1 try to send mail to user1 (address from outlook cache) and mail undelivered. if they choice address from GAL -all ok.

Question: how to remove from outlook cache (it is local file in user profile) only one, wrong address?

Comment: Search for [nk2](http://www.google.com/search?q=nk2) for tools built to make the nickname cache, how to back it up, migrate it and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You start typing the address and when it pops up, highlight it and hit the delete key.  That will remove just that one cached address from the NK2 file.

*edit since this grew longer than a comment response*

I'm not sure how worth it it would be to find a utility that would manage 500 users' NK2 files individually and do this yourself to clear out only SOME old addresses.  If it were me, I would make everyone aware of what is going on and why their mail may get bounced sending to some users and how they themselves could clear out their own cache address by address if they have this problem.  You may have to hold the hand of less-knowledgeable users yourself, but you will avoid potentially corrupting NK2 files using a utilty behind the scenes.  You could always just wipe out their NK2 files altogether as well, but again you should let users know beforehand so you don't get tickets asking why names no longer pop up.

Comment: but 500 users... impossible to come to everybody

Answer (score 0):

How long ago did you make the change?  By default, accoring to [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/841273), the Offline Address Book will be updated in anywhere from a couple hours to 48 hours.

You can try manually downloading the OAB to the client by doing the following:

1. On the Tools menu, point to
   Send/Receive, and then click
   Download Address Book.
2. In the Offline Address Book dialog box,
   make sure that the Download changes
   since last Send/Receive check box is
   checked.
3. Click OK.

Comment: I think the OP is referring to the Outlook nickname cache, not the offline address list.

Comment: @joeqwerty, after reading the question again, I think you could be right.